# "I feel closer to you" to your friend?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm moving and writing a letter to my close friend. And I wanted to say that I felt like I knew her longer and that "I felt close to you" (as a friend)

Is it weird to say "I felt close to you" or "I felt like I'm really close to you" to your friends

Answer (score 2):

To say that your friendship progressed very quickly, you could say

> I felt we were old friends from childhood.
>   I felt we got to know each other very quickly.
>   In the short amount of time we knew each other, we just seemed to click.
>   You were really easy to get to know.

If you say

> I felt like I *was* really close to you
>   I feel like I'm really close to you

it may be interpreted as having romantic overtones, more idiomatic would be

> I felt we were really close friends.

Of course you may want to end with something like

> I hope we will continue to be friends in the future.